# Add Link Text Back to Insert/edit link Box

Tags: links, title

Version 4.2.1 of WordPress removed the link text from the Insert/edit link box.

How can i add it back?

Comment: You will need to add the title text back manually as WordPress no longer adds this text to the field when you insert a new link.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `Links` in admin menu then run `/wp-admin/options.php` find key `link_manager_enabled` and set value to 1. Save.

Comment: No. He means when using the Insert/Edit Link feature included in the editor.

Comment: Thanks Brad for editing the question. I've guessed the meaning wrong. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right, WordPress has been removing the title of the links in several versions before.

There are many ways to solve this problem.

One of the easiest ways to rebuild the title field for links is to use the plugin

Sample in WordPress repository

https://wordpress.org/plugins/title-and-nofollow-for-links/